# How to run a selenium python script inside php

Tags: php, python, selenium

I want to create a functionality that will automate a website, click a select option and scrape the content using php.

I currently have this python selenium script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(thesite)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('CurrentPort'))

select.select_by_value('5')
```

when i run this script alone it works perfectly as it opens firefox, login to that website, and change the value of the dropdown.

How am I going to run this python script inside my php file and pass a value? I found on other questions that `exec()` method on php will do the thing but when i try this, `echo exec('python mytesting.py 2>&1');` it's just giving me this on my browser and not running the python script `operable program or batch file.`

I'm quite new to this and don't know how to properly do this.

Comment: Which OS you run your script ? Error look like you using windows, and your exec is for linux ?

Comment: what do you mean by "Error look like you using windows, and your exec is for linux"? Im running my script on windows

Comment: Probably you didn't set up your windows environment to Python interpreter with  `python` shorcut. Please, check https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#setting-envvars